# EF6 Navigation Properties map empty collection instead of null

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I use linq to entities to fetch one to many relation.
One Client has many Accounts.

```
            var query = from c in db.Client
                        where c.MetaProps.Deleteflag == 0
                        && c.ContractNumber.Equals(clientNumber)
                        select new
                        {
                            Client = c,
                            Accounts = c.Accounts.Where(a => a.IsActive),  
                        };
            contract = query.FirstOrDefault().Client;
```

The problem is that when there are no accounts in the DB the Accounts list is null. Is there a way to init it as an empty list, like when `.Include()` is used?

Comment: Have you tried creating the list in the default constructor?

Comment: @Swell there's no default constructor for anonymous types.  I don't know if this method's returning a tuple or what, but that'd be its own little code smell.

Comment: @Swell I will use yor solution for now, thanks. If you write it as answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can use a null coalescing operator.

```
var query = from c in db.Client
            where c.MetaProps.Deleteflag == 0
            && c.ContractNumber.Equals(clientNumber)
            select new
            {
                Client = c,
                Accounts = c.Accounts.Where(a => a.IsActive) ?? Enumerable.Empty<Account>()  
            };
contract = query.FirstOrDefault().Client;
```

Comment: I got: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Vault.Models.DbModels.Account] Empty[Account]()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: @Evgeni either you'll have to include `System.Linq` in your `using`s or you'll just have to coalesce it after you make the DB call and have your anonymous type in hand.